# My code generates an infinite loop

Tags: vba, excel

My code paste the same formula throughout all of the H2 column. I dont see anywhere in the code where it should do that.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Range("F2").Activate
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
          Pickle = ActiveCell.Address
          ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
          ActiveCell.Value = "=IF(" + Pickle + " <TODAY(),""Send Reminder"",""Do not Send Reminder"") "
          ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
     End If 
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Comment: Sorry got creative with my varible names

Comment: Could it be: `IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)`?

Comment: Try to find last row F `lastrowF = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` And then Autofill your formula, after inserting on the 1st cell:  
`Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("H2:H" & lastrowF)`

Comment: @danieltakeshi i dont completly understand what you are saying, could you put that into an example?

Comment: @Schott.Ben Use the answer from Scott Craner. Autofill is the black point on the bottom of the selected cell that you click twice and fill the cells automatically

Comment: Unrelated. Do not use `ActiveCell` or `Select`. Use a direct reference, like `Set r = Range("F2")` and `r.Offset(0,2).Value`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No loop needed. Use `.FormulaR1C1`

Do not use Activate and Select, they slow down the code

```
Dim lastrow As Long
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("H2:H" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2] <TODAY(),""Send Reminder"",""Do not Send Reminder"") "
End With
```

This puts the formula in all the cells at once and the RC[-2] properly refers to the same row in Column F

Comment: @Schott.Ben great! See that hollow green checkmark? Click it!